# Add methods in collections

Tags: java, collections

I am new to this collection's concept in Java. And from the below code I could see the elements are added using the method "a1.add". Here comes my question, is the add method implemented anywhere like how it is for the Linkedlist

```
import java.util.*;  
class TestCollection1{  
 public static void main(String args[]){  

  ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();//creating arraylist  
  al.add("Ravi");//adding object in arraylist  
  al.add("Vijay");  
  al.add("Ravi");  
  al.add("Ajay");  

  Iterator itr=al.iterator();//getting Iterator from arraylist to traverse        
  while(itr.hasNext()){  
   System.out.println(itr.next());  
  }  
 }  
}
```

Comment: Before asking you can google it any way. check this link:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_linkedlist_class.htm

Comment: You have great giant: Google.com. :)
I am sure it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  LinkedList<String> al=new LinkedList<String>();
```

In both the list data add same type.
  if u want to go in detail then

please read following link.
    http://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-arraylist-and-linkedlist

Comment: It is better to include relavant part from referenced material in your answer. This will help to retain answer even if referenced content is taken away.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this method is implemented somewhere. If you are using Eclipse or IntelliJ, you can hold the Ctrl key while clicking on the `add` name, which will take you to the implementation of that code. If that doesn’t work or you are using another IDE, ask your teacher.

By the way, the last part of the code looks as if you are stuck in the year 2004. Nowadays, we don’t directly use `Iterator` anymore:

```
for (String name : al) {
  System.out.println(name);
}
```

Under the hood, this code does exactly the same, but it is easier to read and more to the point.